# Perforce Streams - Importing a stream which imports other streams

Tags: perforce, p4v

When importing a stream, is there a way to have the files from the imported stream's imports pulled into the workspace?

For example:

StreamA

StreamB imports StreamA

StreamC imports StreamB

I would like to know if there is a way for a workspace of StreamC to have the files from StreamC, StreamB and StreamA.  From my testing, Perforce will only populate a StreamC workspace with files from StreamC and StreamB.  If this is not possible or intentionally not allowed, what is the rationale?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because an `import` operates at the depot path level, rather than at the stream level.  So if you have:

```
import //depot/streamB/...
```

you're not importing all of the files mapped by `streamB`, you're only mapping the files in the named depot path.

There is not presently a way to refer to the files mapped by a stream as a unit -- mostly people "fake it" by using the depot path, but as you've discovered, if the stream uses anything other than the default `share ...` `Path` definition, they aren't really the same thing.